# Derivative of an Integral with Two Functions as Bounds

Tags: calculus, integration

I've been asked to find the derivative of $$g(x)= \int_{\cos x}^{x^4}\sqrt{2-u} du$$
using the Fundamental Theorem of Calculus part 1, and I know I should be substituting and setting a variable to one of the bounds, but I'm not sure how to tackle this with both bounds being functions. Any advice is incredibly appreciated.

Comment: Do you know how to calculate differentials of functions of multible variables? I need to know because my answer will be different if you do...

Comment: If that is your problem, you could assume $c \in [\cos(x),x^4]$ and write the integral as two separate integrals.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The fundamental theorem of calculus says that $$g(x)=\frac d {dx}\,\int_{a(x)}^{b(x)}f(u)\,du=f(b(x))\, b'(x)-f(a(x))\, a'(x)$$ In your case $$f(u)=\sqrt{2-u}\quad,\quad a(x)=\cos(x) \quad,\quad b(x)=x^4$$ So, just apply.

If the presence of two bounds makes a problem to you, just consider that $$\int_{a(x)}^{b(x)} =\int_{a(x)}^{0}+\int_{0}^{b(x)}=\int_{0}^{b(x)}-\int_0^{a(x)}$$

Comment: Isn't that called the newton-leibniz formula?

Comment: @G-man. You are totally correct !

Comment: This is not the fundamental theorem of calculus.

Comment: @YvesDaoust. Let us say that this is  the second fundamental theorem of calculus or the Newton–Leibniz axiom.

Comment: @ClaudeLeibovici: usually they show it with the partial derivative of the integrand in addition (of course vanishing here).

Answer (score 2):

By the fundamental theorem,

$$g(x)= \int_{\cos(x)}^{x^4}\sqrt{2-u}\,du=\left.F(u)\right|_{\cos(x)}^{x^4}=F(x^4)-F(\cos(x))$$ where $F(u)$ is the antiderivative of $f(u)=\sqrt{2-u} $.

Then, by the chain rule,

$$g'(x)=4x^3f(x^4)-\sin(x)f(\cos(x))=4x^3\sqrt{2-x^4}-\sin(x)\sqrt{2-\cos(x)}$$

Answer (score 0):

Applying Fundamental Theorem of Calculus, one should get $$g(x)=\int_{\cos x}^{x^4}\sqrt{2-u}\ du$$ 
$$g'(x)=\sqrt{2-x^4}\cdot \frac{d}{dx}(x^4)-\sqrt{2-\cos x}\cdot \frac{d}{dx}(\cos x)$$
$$=\sqrt{2-x^4}\cdot (4x^3)-\sqrt{2-\cos x}\cdot (-\sin x)$$
 $$=4x^3\sqrt{2-x^4}+\sin x\sqrt{2-\cos x}$$